# localhost refuses to connect after trying to move live server to mamp

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

So I downloaded the files, moved them into the htdocs folder of MAMP. I also imported the SQL and then ran:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 
'http://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/test-site') WHERE 
option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 
'http://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/test-site');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 
replace(meta_value,'http://www.example.com','http://localhost/test-
site');
```

I replaced example.com with the site name and replaced localhost/test-site with localhost:8888/foldername/

This made 0 70 and 0 changes. I then went into my wp-config inside of /htdocs/folder and changed the db name to the the folder name, username to root, password to root

Now when I try loading up my localhost it says:

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

it also takes the port 8888 out of the url

Any help as to what may have gone wrong? I usaully don't work on pre-made sites so I have no idea as to what went wrong with creating a local version I could work off of.

Comment: You didn't put 8888 in your DB config. The easiest way for local development is to set the URLS in your wp-config file. `define(WP_SITEURL, 'http://localhost:8888/test-site/`);` also define `WP_HOMEURL` the same. See more here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php&ved=0ahUKEwiE6oOplJbTAhXp6oMKHX-VBBIQFggcMAE&usg=AFQjCNG5IH5i4xbPR9ujioXWCKPovgAZwA&sig2=Paa22oAfVprwplmAjMU9tg  these values in your wp-config will always override your DB values

Comment: Thanks that did it!